# Python3: What's wrong with my Singleton class and why can't I instantiate it?

Tags: python-3.x

Trying to create a Singleton class to fetch and manage data like following but I keep getting RunTimeError, not sure if `cls.stock_data` is correct here either.

```
class StockData:
    __instance = None
    
    def __init__(self):
        raise RuntimeError("Call instance()")
    
    @classmethod
    def instance(cls):
        if cls.__instance is None:
            cls.__instance = cls()
            cls.__instance.__dict__ = {}
            cls.stock_data = {}
        return cls.__instance
    
    def save_stock_data_from_yahoo(self, stock_symbol):
        import urllib.request
        import json
        url = "http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=" + stock_symbol + "&f=sl1d1t1c1ohgv&e=.csv"
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        data = response.read().decode("utf-8")
        data = data.split(',')
        self.stock_data = {
            "symbol": data[0],
            "last_trade_price": data[1],
            "date": data[2],
            "time": data[3],
            "change": data[4],
            "change_in_percent": data[5],
            "open": data[6],
            "high": data[7],
            "low": data[8],
            "volume": data[9],
            "average_daily_volume": data[10],
            "previous_close": data[11],
            "price_per_sales": data[12],
            "price_per_book": data[13],
            "pe_ratio": data[14],
            "dividend_per_share": data[15],
            "dividend_yield": data[16],
            "earnings_per_share": data[17],
            "ebitda": data[18],
            "market_cap": data[19],
            "one_year_target_price": data[20],
            "price_earnings_ratio": data[21],
            "price_earnings_growth_ratio": data[22],
            "price_sales_ratio": data[23],
            "price_book_ratio": data[24],
            "short_ratio": data[25],
            "day_range": data[26],
            "day_range_realtime": data[27],
            "year_range": data[28]
        }
        
    def get_stock_data(self):
        print(self.stock_data)
        return self.stock_data
    
StockData.instance()
```

Comment: You’re raising a `RuntimeError` in `__init__`. If you don’t want a `RuntimeError` whenever your object is initialised, don’t do that.

Comment: As an aside, why on earth are you doing `cls.__instance.__dict__ = {}`???